# How can I kill the Werewolf?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In the quest "Wild at Heart", the main enemy is a werewolf. This fight turned out to be surprisingly difficult, even though I'm at the appropriate level for the quest.

The main problem is that the werewolf starts regenerating health at some point. This means I have to play more aggressively to deal more damage than he heals, which tends to get me killed.

Is there any way to stop the regeration? Any other tips on how to win this fight?

Comment: I'm stuck at the same point. I already tried bombs containing a lot of silver. Also I guessed that you could lure in the two bears outside the hut, but they're too fat to fit through the wooden beams. Also tried luring out the werewolf to the bears, but he always runs back into his cave. Maybe you can lure him out to the bears in the middle of night at fullmoon... I'm looking forward to reading other players' approach. And by the way: I like the fact that there are quests for which the solution is not that obvious.

Comment: Have you tried reading a book about werewolves? They usually give you useful advice on how to fight them.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, too. Haven't found one yet.

Comment: I had a sword with 10% chance of poisoning. The poisoning helps a lot, since it pretty much negates the regen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Werewolf can be killed using detailed knowledge about werewolves.

There is a book called "Beast's clothes" which will teach a lot about werewolves and the weaknesses they have.

The book will add a beastiary entry containing information on which signs, bombs, oils and strategies to use. I don't want to spoil your experience here, so I will let you find the book (for me it was in a chest in a bandit camp, seemed random). If you don't wanna find it yourself, I will add a spoiler area at the bottom of this post.

I just managed to defeat it yesterday after doubting that it was even possible.

**Werewolf weaknesses (Spoiler):**

> **Oil:** Cursed Oil
>  **Bombs:** Moondust, Devil's Puffball
>  **Signs:** Igni
>
>  You should be aware of the fact that he can summon other wolves to help him. Usually he only does this once. Also, preparing some potions like Swallow for Vitality regeneration or Thunderbolt for more damage will also help you in this fight. I managed to defeat the Werewolf at Level 5. My damage output was bigger than his ability to regenerate his health. Just keep the damage coming with the weapons and utilities mentioned above and don't forget to dodge his attacks.

Comment: I managed to beat him at level 4 (after dying a lot)...the Viper sword (chance of poisoning) helps immensely, but the strategy that sealed the deal for me was to use Axii (with all three ranks of Delusion), instead of Igni.  I only used Igni to kill the wolves he starts with...after that, I just kept re-casting Axii at the werewolf to keep him from being able to attack me, and get free crits from backstabbing him.  After dying at least a dozen times with Igni, the Axii strategy worked on the first try.

Comment: @Liesmith May I ask if you recall being combat focused? I'm level 4 and the only way I can beat it's healing is throwing Igni at him but I don't have any combat skills yet as I'm going mostly sign and alchemy...Tumbling around doing igni isn't turning out fantastic either as my stamina growth is only giving me a little edge and this thing is a pretty heavy hitter.

Comment: @Rig I don't remember what my focus was way back at level 4, but if I had any combat focus, it was just in fast attack damage.  I think the main aid (aside from Axii) is the poison effect from the Viper sword.  This really cuts down on the werewolf's healing at such low levels.

Answer (score 3):

I just finished this, and yeah it was a lot harder then I thought it would be!

- First thing is to kill the wolves that he summons first! get them out of the way so you can focus on the werewolf.
- Before the start of the fight i used the cat potion so i could see a lot easier and also add the Cursed oil to your sword, it increases attack damage. Strait away i then used a thunderbolt potion so i could get rid of the wolves real quick.
- Had another thunderbolt potion and focused on a one on one with the werewolf. I used the AXII sign to stun him and then hit him with 3-5 quick attacks then dive out the way, wait for your stamina to recover and repeat.

This is the way i defeated him, his recovering health wasn't to much of a problem, just get rid of those wolves before you start attacking the werewolf.

Hope this some what helps mate, never posted here before.

Answer (score -1):

you can also sneak around him ^^ he is dead if you get back outside

Answer (score -2):

Use beast oil on your sword it increases the damage done alot

Comment: Could you add a "strategy" besides "Hit a little harder" ?

Comment: Beast oil does not increase damage done to werewolves; cursed oil does.

Answer (score -5):

Kill his wolf companions and then go to town on him.

> Goes to cutscenes let him kill his wife's sister

Comment: Consider explaining your answer as a strategy or methodical steps. Also try to avoid posted potential spoilers.

Comment: Just did it today,level 5. The way I did it was to kill the wolves first, then drop the ww to about a third of his health just before he starts regenerating. Then drink all 3 thunder something green potions and put the anti cursed oil, and axii him. Hit him quickly about 3-4 times and dodge back. About 3 times like this and he was done. Worked 3 times. But I didn't try fighting him after the interlude.